# Difference between integrals

Tags: calculus, functions

What's the difference between
$\int_0^xf(x)dx $ and $\int_0^xf(x')dx'$?
Please give examples with the explanation!
Why ist wrong to integrate $\int_0^xf(x)dx $

Comment: What does $x'$ denote, and are you sure that upper limit of the second integral is $x$ and not $x'$?

Comment: The first expression doesn't make any sense. The boundaries and the integration variable cannot have the same letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int_0^xf(x)dx$ is a wrong expression, because you cannot integrate over $x$ on an interval $[0,x]$ (if $x$ increases, then the boundary would increase too).

$\int_0^xf(x')dx'$ is the way to write it down (or $\int_0^xf(t)dt$, just choose any dummy variable you like). Then you get $\int_0^xf(x')dx'=F(x)-F(0)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus, where $F'(x)=f(x)$.